# The provider 'AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider' specified for the defaultProvider does not exist

Tags: acumatica

I am getting following error while designing page in Visual studio 17 or 19 using Acumatica template.

It is working fine in Acumatica version up to 19.1.x and it is thronging  error from Acumatica 19.2.x onwards.

Sometime it fixes by running Tannate maintenance, but most of the time I have to recreate the page again

**Error Rendering Control - dsAn unhandled exception has occurred.
The provider 'AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider' specified for the defaultProvider does not exist in the providers collection.**

I am looking forward for suggestion to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same very frustrating issue and was told by Acumatica support that the page templates don't work post Visual Studio 2015.  They advised me to use the Customization Project Editor in Acumatica to build pages and once I figured out how to do this, I've been successful.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It works fine for Acumatica 19.1x in both VS 2017 & VS2019.. I am facing this issue only from Acumatica 19.2x onwards

Comment: I think they may have said that the templates weren't updated since VS 2015.  Eventually they became incompatible.